# Converting Java hash to C# and need help understanding the Java

Tags: c#, java

I'm converting a Java library over to C# as I rewrite a legacy application and I need some assistance. I need to understand what this line in Java is doing:

```
sb.append(Integer.toHexString((b & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3))
```

and if this C# line is equivalent

```
result += (Convert.ToInt32(b).ToString("x2") + " ").Substring(1,3);
```

In both cases b is a byte from a SHA-1 hash that the code is looping through.
The Java part I don't understand is ((b & 0xFF) | 0x100). It looks like it's padding it?

Ordinarily I would compare the output from the Java application to what my C# is generating but I am not in a postition to do that right now (and it's frustrating me - trust me).

Comment: '&' is bitwise logical "AND", it will check every bit of the variables under comparison, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm

Comment: From a cursory read, 0xAA would become `"1AA"` in java and `"AA "` in C#. But maybe I missed something.

Comment: b & 0xFF will mask the lowest byte , so whatever b is, you will get something between 0x00 and 0xFF. In the resulting integer, 9th bit is set, no matter what it was before. So you'll have something between 0x0100 to 0x01FF. From that string  the substring from index 1 to 3 is cropped. So you'll end up with a String that resembles a Hex Value between 100 and 1FF.

Comment: Why are you adding a space to your string before calling Substring?

Comment: Ooops, correcting myself: the substring(1,3) will give you the last two digits which will be something between 00 and FF. The |0x100 is a neat trick to have Integer.toHexString give you a leading zero for the last two digits which it wouldn't according to it's javadoc ...

Comment: I believe `ToInt16` instead of `ToInt32` of would make them equivalent, unless they are equivalent, in which case - I don't know.

Comment: Finally home and can accept/upvote (stupid work network). T045T - I added the space because I wasn't paying attention to what I was typing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the original that drastically - the C# equivalent (assuming 'sb' is a StringBuilder) is just:

```
sb.Append(((b & 0xFF) | 0x100).ToString("x").Substring(1, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I was able to find someone with the Java code running and test the output and everything matched nicely. Hooray for unit tests! Thanks, Dave!

Answer (score 1):

`b & 0xFF` will mask the lowest byte. So whatever `b` is, you will get something between 0x00 and 0xFF.

In the resulting integer, 9th bit is set, no matter what it was before. So you'll have something between 0x0100 to 0x01FF.

From that string the substring from index 1 to 3 is cropped. It will give you the last two digits which will be something between 00 and FF. The |0x100 is a neat trick to have Integer.toHexString give you a leading zero for the last two digits which it wouldn't according to it's javadoc ...

If I remeber correctly, your C# code does not exactly the same. But I hope with this explanation you can build it up yourself :)